# How to make services ran on my Ubuntu 16.04 accessible from outside

Tags: services, ip

I have an `Ubuntu 16.04` which I want to serve some services on it and access them from other systems in my local network by my local IP address; but I can't.

For example, I have installed and started an `Elasticsearch` service on my system. I can access `http://127.0.0.1:9201` from a browser on the same system, but I can not access `http://172.18.10.29:9201` from the same browser; `172.18.10.29` is my IP address in my local network. `telnet` from another system in the network to `172.18.10.29 9201` also fails. This is what `nmap` from another system in the network shows:

```
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-11-12 16:37 IRST
Nmap scan report for 172.18.10.29
Host is up (0.00038s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

The last one is an `Elasticsearch` related port.

[This](http://textuploader.com/dlvpr) is what `iptables-save` shows.

**EDIT 1:**

For the `Elasticsearch` case, I have tried to config `network-host` to my local IP address. It is now accessible at `http://172.18.10.29:9201` from a browser in my own machine, but can't be reached from another machine in my network.

Comment: I have never even heard of Elasticsearch but from your description it sounds like it's listening only on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1), not the other interface(s). Perhaps that will help you get started.

Comment: @MarkSmith, I have tried configuring that but it wasn't successful. Review my edits please.

Comment: Use `sudo ss -tulp` to see which applications are listening on which network ports.  Are the applications you want listening actually doing so?